# Vue 2 Laravel 5.3 vue-toastr

Tags: laravel-5.3, vuejs2, webpack-style-loader, vue-loader

> NOTE: Please refer to the comment on the suggested answer if you failed to
>   find any flaw in your codes or no console log error appeared.

Anyone has experience on vue-toastr please help on the following. I follow the instruction on [here](https://github.com/AStaroverov/vue-toast). seems that the js is being read properly (I guess) after the following code

```
import VueToast from 'vue-toast'
```

This is my first time to import css into Vue component. Did a bit of research and I think I have vue-loader which should includes vue-style-loader as mention [here](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-style-loader) (correct if i am wrong) and I used the following code to import vue-toastr css

```
import '!!vue-style-loader!css-loader!vue-toast/dist/vue-toast.min.css'
```

I load the page and click on the button but no toastr is shown, nor any console log errors. I herewith attach the full version of my codes below and please help.

```
<template>
    <div>
    <button @click.prevent="toastIt">Click</button>
    <vue-toast ref='toast'></vue-toast>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
  import '!!vue-style-loader!css-loader!vue-toast/dist/vue-toast.min.css'
  import VueToast from 'vue-toast'
  export default {
    components:{
      'vue-toast': VueToast,
    },
    data(){
      return{
        user:{},
        shop:{}
      }
    },
    props:[
    ],
    created(){
    },
    mounted(){
    },
    updated(){
    },
    methods:{
      toastIt(){
        this.$refs.toast.showToast['hihi']
      }
    },
    computed:{

    }
  }
</script>
```

## EDIT 1

After the round bracket edit, I tried it but still nothing popped up. But everytime I click the button it seems fetching things without any errors in console log. Please help! 
[image: Network]

EDIT#2

From the image below. It seems that the vue-toast is being read and there is actually element of the toastr in the page. And everytime I click on the button there is update in the div of vue-toast but nothing can be observed from the page.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a syntax error: `this.$refs.toast.showToast['hihi']`.
You want to call the method `showToast` by using parenthesis instead of square brackets: `this.$refs.toast.showToast('hihi')`.

Full code:

```
<template>
    <div>
    <button @click.prevent="toastIt">Click</button>
    <vue-toast ref='toast'></vue-toast>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
  import '!!vue-style-loader!css-loader!vue-toast/dist/vue-toast.min.css'
  import VueToast from 'vue-toast'
  export default {
    components:{
      'vue-toast': VueToast,
    },
    data(){
      return{
        user:{},
        shop:{}
      }
    },
    props:[
    ],
    created(){
    },
    mounted(){
    },
    updated(){
    },
    methods:{
      toastIt(){
        this.$refs.toast.showToast('hihi')
      }
    },
    computed:{

    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response @aristidesfl. It seems to have no errors still but nothing happening on the page....

Comment: Thank you for your helps. This is actually the entire code of my .vue which other part do you need of my project? jsbin not sure how to run on it sorry about that... coz I actually use laravel 5.4 on my project

Comment: please refer to my EDIT#2, it seems to be working at the backend after I click the button the div has update. but nothing can be observed from the page visually.

Comment: Sorry that this is very dumb of me, and I hope there is no other people will fall to this stupid mistake like me. It was because my background is in white color, and by default vue-toast was using white color as the text and no background color on the toastr if you do not set the theme. So that I realized the words actually popped up at the bottom of the screen. Now once I set the theme to info it worked just nicely. Thanks a lot @aristidesfl for your instruction and supports.